Discretisation of measurable function for simple functions approximation
In the classic proof of Rudin, Principles of mathematical analysis, Th 11.20, the discretisation of the range of the measurable function $f$ is with step $1/2^n$ for the interval [0,n], generating $n2^n$ points. Why not $1/n$, thus generating only $n^2$ points (or $1/n^2$, thus generating only $n^3$ points, if $n\times\text{step}$ is required to vanish, which does not seem so at first reading...) and so on? The proof does not seem to suffer, by just replacing $(j-1)/2^n$ with $(j-1)/n$ in the definition of the simple function.
EDIT: my proposed simplified construction implicitly assumes taking running maxima of the simple functions thus constructed, as noted by the comment below.
I would like to make an additional point here, besides the precise partitioning method. Why does one not use a similar machinery as when dealing with Riemann integration (on the range of $f$ instead of its domain of course)? That is, whatever the step size is, to preserve monotonicity, just define successive refinements of partitions with vanishing mesh, extended to larger and larger intervals $[0,n]$ obviously (just take unions). It would seem more natural and general... whereas the literature always uses this $1/2^n$ discretisation step, which seems quite arbitrary, because it is just a particular way of implementing the refinement of partitions aforementioned, which seems sufficient to me.

You won't get an increasing sequence if you use $\frac 1 n$.

oh I see! One could consider the maximum of all the simple functions thus constructed though, wouldn't that fix it? I think the max of simple functions is still simple.

If $a_n \to a$ you cannot say $\max {a_1,a_2,...,a_n} \to a$. Take $a_n$ decreasing, for example.

but in our case all $a_n\le a$ by construction (your $a$ would be my $f$), clearly the decreasing scenario would not be admissible otherwise convergence of $a_n$ to $a$ would not be possible. It is merely a squeeze argument, since $a_n\le\max{a_i}\le a$ so for the sequence of running maxima, the convergence is both to $a$ and monotone

Here is a sufficient condition for the sequence to be increasing. Let $(a^{(n)})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a strictly increasing sequence of positive integers so that $a^{(n)}\uparrow \infty$ and let $f:X\to [0,\infty)$ be a measurable function. If we define the sequence $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ by
$$f_n=\sum_{k=0}^{na^{(n)}-1}\frac{k}{a^{(n)}}\mathbf{1}_{f^{-1}([k/a^{(n)},(k+1)/a^{(n)}))}+n\mathbf{1}_{f^{-1}([n,\infty))}$$
then $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is an increasing sequence if $a^{(n+1)}/a^{(n)}\in \mathbb{N}/\{1\}$ for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
Indeed, let $x\in f^{-1}([k^*/a^{(n)},(k^*+1)/a^{(n)}))$ for some arbitrary $k^*< na^{(n)}$. There exists one $\ell^*$ s.t. $x \in f^{-1}([k^*/a^{(n)},(k^*+1)/a^{(n)})\cap [\ell^*/a^{(n+1)},(\ell^*+1)/a^{(n+1)}))$ so that
$$f_{n+1}(x)-f_n(x)=\ell^*/a^{(n+1)}-k^*/a^{(n)}$$
Now we find $(\ell^*_d,\ell^*_u)$ s.t.
$$k^*/a^{(n)}=\ell^*_d/a^{(n+1)}\implies \ell^*_d=k^*a^{(n+1)}/a^{(n)}$$
$$(k^*+1)/a^{(n)}=\ell^*_u/a^{(n+1)}\implies \ell^*_u=(k^*+1)a^{(n+1)}/a^{(n)}$$
so
$$\begin{aligned}
\small{[\ell^*_d/a^{(n+1)},\ell^*_u/a^{(n+1)})}&=\small{\bigcup_{0\leq m<a^{(n+1)}/a^{(n)}}[(k^*a^{(n+1)}/a^{(n)}+m)/a^{(n+1)},(k^*a^{(n+1)}/a^{(n)}+m+1)/a^{(n+1)})}\\
\end{aligned}$$
so $\ell^*\geq k^*a^{(n+1)}/a^{(n)}$ and we conclude $f_{n+1}(x)\geq f_n(x)$. Now let $x \in f^{-1}([n,\infty))$. Either $x \in f^{-1}([n+1,\infty))$, in which case $f_{n+1}(x)-f_n(x)=1>0$, or there exists one $\ell^*$ s.t. $x \in f^{-1}([n,\infty)\cap [\ell^*/a^{(n+1)},(\ell^*+1)/a^{(n+1)}))$ so that
$$f_{n+1}(x)-f_n(x)=\ell^*/a^{(n+1)}-n$$
Now we find $\ell^*_d$ s.t. $n=\ell^*_d/a^{(n+1)}\implies \ell^*_d=na^{(n+1)}$ so
$$[\ell^*_d/a^{(n+1)},\infty)=\bigcup_{0\leq m < a^{(n+1)}}[(na^{(n+1)}+m)/a^{(n+1)},(na^{(n+1)}+m+1)/a^{(n+1)})$$
so $\ell^*\geq na^{(n+1)}$ and we conclude $f_{n+1}(x)\geq f_n(x)$. So $f_{n+1}\geq f_n$.

I think this is quite a stronger condition than just refining arbitrary partitions of [0,n], accordingly extended as n grows, as suggested in the edit. Wouldn' t that suffice?

@xyz yes the refinement argument you mention in the edit appears fine to me. This was just to show that $a^{(n)}=2^n$ is a special case of the above. It seems to me that $2^n$ is usually chosen because it is simple and clear enough to conclude that $|f(x)-f_n(x)|\leq 1/2^n$ on ${f<n}$.
